# Error Installing Python Library "Boto3" Using Pip Install

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, pip, boto3

I am trying to install the python package "boto3" into an EC2 instance with both python and pip successfully installed.

I am attempting to run both of the following commands:

`python -v -m pip install boto3-1.13.5.tar.gz`

`python -v -m pip install boto3-1.9.149-py2.py3-none-any.whl`

However when I run the commands they both come back with `[Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/botocore/`

Or more specifically:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f9e06d63910>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/botocore/
```

I have tried to test whether they libraries successfully download by using the following series of commands but, I can attest that they have yet to successfully install due to the error presented below:

`python`
`import boto3`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'
```

How can I solve this Hanging issue on the Network being unreachable?

Answer (score 0):

as it said in the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/quickstart.html#installation)  you can install boto3 by the following command:

```
pip install boto3
```

or if you are on Linux you should try:

```
python3 -m pip install boto3
```

and if it failed again it must be your package manager or something with python version or even your network, maybe trying to run a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) then installing boto3 will solve the problem (for Linux):

```
python3 -m venv env
source ./env/bin/activate
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it able to install other packages of python? 
If no then Check your security group as it is unable to connect to the outside network.

If yes then try with this command:

`pip install boto3`